# Setting a nullable double to null

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Why can't I do this?

```
bool flag = true;
double? n = flag ? 12 : null;
```

If the type is nullable why I can't i set it to a null value?

Comment: Side note - you should use `12` instead of `n = 12`

Comment: Yeah sorry i just made this code, wasn't copied